# What does "<-" do in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I recently stumbled across this bit of example code in Racket's `ffi` documentation:

```racket
(let-values ([(data meta) (read-sound* "/tmp/x.wav")])
  (printf ">>> data-length: ~s\n>>> meta: ~s\n" (length data) meta)
  (let* ([data data #;
               (list-of (list (add-half (1st x) (1st y))
                              (add-half (2nd x) (2nd y)))
                        (x <- data
                           and
                           y <- (append (repeated-list (list 0.0 0.0) 11025) data)
                           and
                           i <- 0.1 0.12 ..))])
```

What does `x <- data`, `y <- ...` and `i <- ...` do?

I could not find any relevant documentation for this notation.

[Link](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/pkgs/racket-doc/ffi/examples/use-sndfile.rkt) to the code in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `#;` comments out the following s-expression, so the entire `list-of` form is commented out in the code sample. [Looking at the linked code](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/pkgs/racket-doc/ffi/examples/use-sndfile.rkt), note that `(require swindle)` is also commented out, suggesting that the relevant definitions may be found there.

Looking at the [documentation for Swindle](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/pkgs/racket-doc/ffi/examples/use-sndfile.rkt), it turns out that the `list-of` form is a list comprehension facility, and that `<-` is used in generator clauses here. In particular, `(v <- ... and v <- ...)` is a parallel generator clause.